# Android - strange flow of MotionEvent in listview

Tags: android, listview

I am observing a very strange behavior in ListView with MotionEvent handling.
I have subclassed ListView in order to add logs. Here is my subclass.

```
public class MyListView extends ListView{
public MyListView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    boolean retVal =  super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    System.out.println("MyListview.dispatchTouchEvent :"+ev.getActionMasked()+" <<>> "+retVal);
    return retVal;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean retVal = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    System.out.println("MyListview.onInterceptTouchEvent :"+ev.getActionMasked()+" <<>> "+retVal);
    return retVal;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean retVal = super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    System.out.println("MyListview.onTouchEvent :"+ev.getActionMasked()+" <<>> "+retVal);
    return retVal;
}
```

}

and, when I fling on this list, I get the following log in logcat.

> 12-26 12:38:32.347: I/System.out(20725):
>   MyListview.onInterceptTouchEvent :0 <<>> false 12-26 12:38:32.348:
>   I/System.out(20725): MyListview.onTouchEvent :0 <<>> true 12-26
>   12:38:32.348: I/System.out(20725): MyListview.dispatchTouchEvent :0
>   <<>> true 12-26 12:38:32.388: I/System.out(20725):
>   MyListview.onTouchEvent :2 <<>> true 12-26 12:38:32.388:
>   I/System.out(20725): MyListview.dispatchTouchEvent :2 <<>> true 12-26
>   12:38:32.405: I/System.out(20725): MyListview.onTouchEvent :2 <<>>
>   true 12-26 12:38:32.405: I/System.out(20725):
>   MyListview.dispatchTouchEvent :2 <<>> true 12-26 12:38:32.422:
>   I/System.out(20725): MyListview.onTouchEvent :2 <<>> true 12-26
>   12:38:32.422: I/System.out(20725): MyListview.dispatchTouchEvent :2
>   <<>> true 12-26 12:38:32.439: I/System.out(20725):
>   MyListview.onTouchEvent :2 <<>> true 12-26 12:38:32.439:
>   I/System.out(20725): MyListview.dispatchTouchEvent :2 <<>> true 12-26
>   12:38:32.455: I/System.out(20725): MyListview.onTouchEvent :2 <<>>
>   true 12-26 12:38:32.455: I/System.out(20725):
>   MyListview.dispatchTouchEvent :2 <<>> true 12-26 12:38:32.473:
>   I/System.out(20725): MyListview.onTouchEvent :2 <<>> true 12-26
>   12:38:32.473: I/System.out(20725): MyListview.dispatchTouchEvent :2
>   <<>> true 12-26 12:38:32.484: I/System.out(20725):
>   MyListview.onTouchEvent :2 <<>> true 12-26 12:38:32.484:
>   I/System.out(20725): MyListview.dispatchTouchEvent :2 <<>> true 12-26
>   12:38:32.484: I/System.out(20725): MyListview.onTouchEvent :1 <<>>
>   true 12-26 12:38:32.484: I/System.out(20725):
>   MyListview.dispatchTouchEvent :1 <<>> true

I am puzzled at the following observations:

1. For ACTION_DOWN(code 0), `onInterceptTouchEvent` is returning 'false', still `onTouchEvent` is called, even for ACTION_DOWN(code 0). Isn't `onTouchEvent`  supposed to be called only if I return true from `onInterceptTouchEvent` ?
2. As I know, as long as `onInterceptTouchEvent`  is returning false, I should keep getting events in `onInterceptTouchEvent`, but that is not happening !. (I don't think any child view is stealing events because all subsequent events are delivered in `MyListView's` `onTouchEvent` itself.)

Can anybody help me understand why I get such logs? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1.The `ListView`'s `onTouchEvent()` will only be called when none of its children has consumed the touch event or itself intercept the touch event(make `onInterceptTouchEvent()` return true).So either your `ListView` doesn't has any child or its child's `onTouchEvent()` returns false thus make `ListView` itself to handle the touch event.

2.If you read the source code of `ViewGroup`'s `dispatchTouchEvent()`,you will find this:

```
        // Check for interception.
        final boolean intercepted;
        if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                || mFirstTouchTarget != null) {
            final boolean disallowIntercept = (mGroupFlags & FLAG_DISALLOW_INTERCEPT) != 0;
            if (!disallowIntercept) {
                intercepted = onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
                ev.setAction(action); // restore action in case it was changed
            } else {
                intercepted = false;
            }
        } else {
            // There are no touch targets and this action is not an initial down
            // so this view group continues to intercept touches.
            intercepted = true;
        }
```

That means the `onInterceptTouchEvent()` will always be called when the touch event is `ACTION_DOWN`,but won't be called when the touch event is not `ACTION_DOWN` and the `mFirstTouchTarget` variable(**a linked list that holds the child view that can be touched**) is null.

So you can make `onInterceptTouchEvent()` be called once when you just touch the screen(`ACTION_DOWN`),but when the touch event continues the method cannot be called any more because `mFirstTouchTarget` is null.And this is often because the `ListView` has no child or all the child's `onTouchEvent()` return false just as I mentioned in my answer above.

If you want to know more about the touch event deliver,read more source code of `View` and its children.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I have moved on with some other design and so I couldn't test or verify your answer.